# How to use concat after as as new field

Tags: sql, select, concatenation

In this select statement

```
Select concat(column1,conlumn2) as concat1
from TblSample
```

How to use `concat1` as my field 
to compare with other fields
For example in my tables :

Example;

```
concat(concat1, Field1) as Concat2
```

is it possible?

Comment: Dunno how to use that

Answer (score 0):

```
Select concat(concat(column1,conlumn2),Field1)  as concat2
from TblSample
```

In you condition (due to comments) you may also use:

```
SELECT concat (C1, C2) from
(
 select some-calculated-column as c1, some-calculated-column as c2 
 from 
 some-tables
)
```

Comment: I have generated two columns the one is from the one the Fields

tblreferrer.referreRname as `Referrer All`, *my comlunm 1* 
max(if(departmentname= '', tblpatienttransaction.referrername,0)) as ReferrerWithValue *my comlunm 2*
is it possible to merger these two tables?


  [1]: http://i.stack.imgur.com/jT1Ku.jpg

Comment: I already tried but the result wasnt my expecation, i just want to merge those two columns, eliminating the same value,
but the result having more day within the field so i just ask another way if you can help.

Answer (score 0):

Use subquery/CTE

```
SELECT *, concat(concat1, Field1) as Concat2
FROM 
(
  Select *, concat(column1,conlumn2) as concat1
  from TblSample
) AS t
```

or `CONCAT` multiple values:

```
Select concat(column1,column2,Field1) AS concat2
from TblSample
```

Comment: I have generated two columns the one is from the one the Fields

tblreferrer.referreRname as `Referrer All`, *my comlunm 1* 
max(if(departmentname= 'ct-scan', tblpatienttransaction.referrername,0)) as ReferrerWithValue *my comlunm 2* 
[![enter image description here][1]][1]
is it possible to merger these two tables?


  [1]: http://i.stack.imgur.com/jT1Ku.jpg